# When using Bootstrap "selectpicker with-ajax" and data-live-search="true" how to get search params from the input box?

Tags: ajax, jsp

```
<input:select class="selectpicker with-ajax" data-live-search="true" id="mySearch">
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" >
   <c:if test="${user.id == form.primaryUserId}">
      <option value="${user.id}" data-subtext="${user.email}" ${user.name}</option>
   </c:if>>
</c:forEach>
</input:select>
```

I am sending list of users to the jsp view to show the primary user first. Then to change the primary user I created a search endpoint which I want to call with Ajax. But the problem is that I have not found the way to get the search params from class="selectpicker with-ajax" as the search box has no ID.

Comment: use class `selectpicker` to get value in jquery and then pass it to ajax .

Comment: @Swati What about if I use multiple selectpickers in one page? It shows just the first one.

Comment: You can used `$(this).val();` to get value of particular selected  `selectpickers`.

Comment: Yes i got the value of selected value but I need the value of the data-live-search="true" search box. Any idea to get this?

Comment: can you post your `html` generated of above code ? it would more clear ?